# declare global forms

Tags: c#, winforms

i want declare on form as global variable and then work with that in app. i dont want use below method to access app forms.

```
Form1 myForm = new Form1();
```

anyone have any idea?

thanks

Comment: I have an idea. Don't do that. Global variables are evil.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There's probably a better way than making the entire form global.

Comment: I'd suggest you read a good book about the basics of C# and Object Oriented Programming first. The way you don't want it to do is the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want your form to be a [Singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998558.aspx), which isn't my favourite pattern, but it beats a global.

Comment: A singleton will do as long as you only Hide and do not Close the Form. But indeed, better than a global.

Comment: Henk is correct.  Calling close will cause the form to be disposed, which means you'll have to recreate it in order to show it again, which would defeat the purpose of the singleton. 

I agree with the other posters that are suggesting the whole idea might be a bad one, but if you have a good reason, it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

my way is declaring a static class which have static variable Form1.

```
public static class Global
{
    private static Form1 myForm = new Form1();
    public static bool Show()
    {

        myForm.Show();
    }

    public static bool Hide()
    {
        myForm.Close();
    }
}
```

it's not good way?

Comment: It's not.  This code will bomb when the user closes the form.  If you prevent the user from closing the form it is a permanent memory leak.  Why do you need this?

Comment: you'll have to make sure Close() is never called, because that disposes the form.

Comment: nobugz: i need this because i want show/hide Form1 eachtime i want.

Jason: thanks, i changed close to hide.

Comment: Make sure you also cancel any user-invoked close on the form and hide it instead, or you'll have the same problem